# Use of Material Science Tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm trying to get some clarity on the scope of the [material-science](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/material-science) tag, or perhaps figure out another tag with the meaning I want.

I was reading [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/383297/how-do-i-determine-the-breaking-point-of-something) and thought that only a tag of "classical mechanics" wasn't really enough to describe his concern.  I looked for tags and added the "material-science" tag, only to second guess myself and roll it back after re-reading the "About" section for the tag. (I realized that I forgot to take out the -Josh like I intended too, so I'm done touching that one)

I'm not sure if the tag would apply here or not.  Based on the description of the tag, I realized the focus seems to be more towards the stricter description of material science.

I'm not sure where we would fit in questions that relate to things like "engineering mechanics" in this case.  The question isn't really about the material properties; it's about the manifestation of those properties and how we would apply that, which is why I rolled the edit back.

Is [solid-mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solid-mechanics) the tag I'm looking for?

I didn't notice this tag until I was making this discussion; but I would like some more input from everyone on if we should use "material-science" for these types of questions as well.

Comment: I think [tag:continuum-mechanics] and [tag:elasticity] are the tags for that question. It's possible [tag:material-science] could apply as well; I'll have to leave it to someone more active in that tag to address that though.

Comment: It most certainly is not materials science. Pure classical mechanics. Now, a question on the failure mechanism of some materisl could be. But not that question.

Comment: @JonCuster That's what was tripping me up.  I find this question especially in a grey area because it's not clear if he's trying to understand the basic effects of increased applied moments of force; or of he wanted a detailed analysis of fracture mechanics (probably the former).

Comment: As phrased, I can only interpret it as applied moments. No hint of mechanisms, deformation, etc.